# SQL Server stored procedure not executing correctly

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Based on a parameter `@hasLocationChanged`, part of the stored procedure should be run (or not):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId = @routeId)
    SET @isUpdate = 0
ELSE
    SET @isUpdate = 1

IF @hasLocationChanged = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC fnUpdateConditionDataByRouteId @routeId, @isUpdate
    EXEC fnUpdateTrafficDataByRouteId @routeId, @isUpdate
    EXEC dbo.InsertmappedConsPlanningandConsHistory @routeId, @AgencyId, @LastSurfType, @LPDepth
END
```

When I am passing value 1 for `@hasLocationChanged` from the application it is getting accepted since the third stored procedure within the second `IF condition` block of code is running but the first two aren't. Is there any way I can understand what is causing the problem. Since I am trying to run this stored procedure using an application it is not returning me with any kind of error.

Comment: Attach the Profiler or use XEvents to sort this out.  You can see each statement that's run and any error messages that are returned.

Comment: How do you know the first two are not called? My guess is that they are being called, but the variable @isUpdate is 0 and so nothing happens.

Comment: I know the first two isn't called because if you look at the first block of IF statement it says IF NOT EXISTS and the record doesn't exist in the table where it should look. Even if it does and @isUpdate is set to 0 then also the two procedures should run and there should be significant change in the values it updates.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I will check it out since I have no idea about those tools.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock But your statement made me think what will happen if somehow isUpdate value is something other than 0 or 1 such as NULL or undefined then it might be a possibility that they are running but not updating. Is it possible?

Comment: isUpdate cannot be null, since the preceding expression is binary. However just guessing from the name fnUpdate.. sounds like something that does an update, whereas a variable isUpdate being 0 sounds like it might prevent an update. Without seeing more of your code, there is no way to help more.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Will it be helpful if I post the whole stored procedure and under what conditions the stored procedure is executed?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock The problem isUpdate is not passed 1 when I am trying to create a new record using this stored procedure but it should be 1. I tested few cases and this is the problem I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure which I thought wasn't running had a block of code commented out which shouldn't